# Create a Range spanning the character before cursor in Word Javascript API / Office.js

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js

I'm trying to create an Office Javascript Add-in which will examine the character before the cursor and replace that character depending on what it is.  So I need to create a Range of the character before the cursor.  I can do this easily with a VBA macro, but unfortunately, I can't find a way to do this with the new javascript api.  Is this possible?

If this is possible, it would also be helpful if I could look at the 5 characters before and after the cursor for added context.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A couple months ago I tried something similar. In short there is no good way to do it. **You could try what I will specify below, but I would advice against it.** The example is not thought through and most likely will contain a number of bugs. Additionally I find this an incredibly inefficient way to do something so simple.

*Limitations in the API that prevent an easy solution:*

- There is no cursor, only selections. This means that you need to make an assumption that the cursor is always at the beginning of a selection.
- Selections cannot be directly modified through the Office.js API. So it is not possible to expand the selection to include the previous character.
- The 'Range' object does allow to be extended into [both directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=office-js#expandto-range-), but it requires another range as input. This means an earlier range needs to created/found (i.e. a range object before the current selection).
- You can only navigate outside of the selection through the property 'parentBody' which will give you the entire body of the document. This needs to be processed in order to isolate a range before the cursor that could help us replace the character.
- From what I can tell it is not possible to create a range for a single character. So a bigger range needs to be taken before the cursor and needs to replaced entirely.

**Example**

```
// WARNING: Incredibly inefficient and poor code. Do not use directly!
// WARNING: Edge cases are not tackled in this example. 

function replaceCharacterBeforeCursor() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var selection = context.document.getSelection();
        // Assumption: Cursor always starts at the beginning of a selection.
        var cursor = selection.getRange('Start');

        // Create a new range that covers everything before the cursor (or the beginning of the selection).
        var startDocument = selection.parentBody.getRange("Start");
        var rangeBeforeSelection = startDocument.expandTo(startDocument);

        // Capture parent paragraph.
        var parentParagraph = rangeBeforeSelection.paragraphs.getLast();
        context.load(parentParagraph);

        context
            .sync()
            .then(function () {

                // Create range that captures everything from the beginning of the parent
                // paragraph until the cursor.
                var paragraphStart = parentParagraph.getRange('Start');
                var wordRangeBeforeCursor = paragraphStart.expandTo(cursor);

                context.load(wordRangeBeforeCursor);

                context
                    .sync()
                    .then(function () {

                        // Replace last character.
                        var oldText = wordRangeBeforeCursor.text;
                        var wordLength = oldText.length;
                        var lastCharacter = oldText.substring(wordLength - 1);

                        if (lastCharacter !== " ") {
                            var newText = oldText.substring(0, wordLength - 1) + "test";
                            wordRangeBeforeCursor.insertText(newText, 'Replace');

                            context.sync();
                        }
                    });
            });
    });
}
```

Another way to do it is through text ranges. This would be substantially more inefficient. Either way I hope this will help you in finding a solution that fits your needs.

Comment: Great post - helped me put together a right-clicked word selection routine (to act on from a Word add-in context menu button). Thank you!